# How to create a checkbox filter for bussines data list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a business data list that is using a parameterised stored procedure to retrieve search results.
SharePoint List Filter is used for selecting desired values that then are sent to the stored procedure.

The SharePoint List Filter looks, how should I put it, a bit dated with its popping out modal window with binary values to select from.

[image]

I am looking for a way to display a checkbox instead that will be send a value into business data list' query.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Igal